# Background color cookie not working in JS

Tags: javascript, cookies

This is my HTML code and due to some unknown reasons the cookie is not created.

```
<select id="selectedColor" onchange="changeColor();">
    <option value="select color">Select Color</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
</select>
```

On changing select the background color is set using the below.

```
function changeColor(){
    var selectedBgColor = document.getElementById("selectedColor").value;
    document.bgColor = selectedBgColor;
    document.cookie = "color="+selectedBgColor+";max-age=3600;";
}
```

While loading cookies in new page it is not working, I took these codes from Kudvenkat tutorial on youtube, he wrote the same code, but it is working in his browser but not working in my browser. Can you please help me solve this problem?

```
window.onload(){
    if(document.cookie.length != 0){
        var splited = document.cookie.split("=");
        document.bgColor = splited[1];
        document.getElementById("selectedColor").value = splited[1];
    }
    else{
        alert("Cookie not found!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Log `splited[1]` to the console, you'll find out what is happening. Also, `bgColor` property is obsoleted, use CSS instead.

Comment: Are you sure your browser is accepting cookies?

Comment: Yes, I am sure cookies are enabled in my browsers

Comment: And the page comes from a website, not the harddisc? I strongly recommend using a well known cookie script instead of writing your own. For example https://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: can you please edit the code and answer it, thank you

Comment: Put `var color = document.cookie.split("color=")[1].split(";")[0]` instead of `var splited = document.cookie.split("=");` and use the color value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should split with ";" first to get property/value pairs. Then split first element (or search color key) with "=" to get value of the color.

Find color:

```
var pairs = document.cookie.split(";");
var color = pairs[0].split("=")[1];
```

Change color:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
```

Comment: Thank you sir, you ended my nightmare